# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x) in iOS Danielgindi charts ChartDataSet entries

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using Charts library (version 3.5.0). Usually the chart is drawn without issue but randomly the app crashes with the following [XCode Crash stack screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRdEc.png) and [Crashlytics stack trace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfGKJ.png)

Class with chart view

```
class ChartContainerView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: CustomLineChartView!

var chartData: LineChartDataSet?

struct TickData: Codable {
    let price: Double
    let time: Int
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ChartContainerView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    chartView.resetChart()
}

func drawChart(withData tickArray: [TickData]) {
    chartView.resetChart()
    var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for (i, tick) in tickArray.enumerated() {
        entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: tick.price))
    }
    chartData = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries)
    let xValueCount = Double(chartData!.count)
    chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = xValueCount
    chartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(60.0 * 5)
    chartView.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(60.0 * 5)
    chartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 5, maxXRange: 2000)
    chartView.data = createLineData(lineDataSet: chartData)
    chartView.moveViewToX(xValueCount)
    chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.5)
}

func createLineData(lineDataSet: LineChartDataSet) -> LineChartData {
    lineDataSet.mode = .cubicBezier
    lineDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = true
    lineDataSet.circleRadius = 2
    lineDataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
    lineDataSet.axisDependency = .right
    lineDataSet.lineWidth = 1
    lineDataSet.fillAlpha = 0
    lineDataSet.highlightLineWidth = 0.3
    lineDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    lineDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = false
    
    return LineChartData(dataSet: lineDataSet)
}

//This method is called on a background thread
func updateChart(withData tickArray: [TickData]) {
    let count = chartData!.count
    for (i, tick) in tickArray.enumerated() {
        let entry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(count + i), y: tick.price))
        chartData?.append(entry)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        chartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
        chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

}

Custom LineChartView

```
class CustomLineChartView: LineChartView {

    override func initialize() {
        super.initialize()
        renderer = CustomLineChartRenderer(dataProvider: self, animator: _animator, viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler)
        
        chartDescription?.enabled = false
        dragYEnabled = false
        scaleYEnabled = false
        pinchZoomEnabled = false
        doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
        dragDecelerationFrictionCoef = 0.0
        highlightPerTapEnabled = false
        autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true
        highlightPerDragEnabled = false
        noDataText = ""
        leftAxis.enabled = false
        legend.enabled = false
        dragXEnabled = true
        scaleXEnabled = false
        
        xAxis.labelCount = 5
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        xAxis.granularity = 1.0
        
        rightAxis.labelCount = 5
        rightAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChart
        rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        rightAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        rightAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
        rightAxis.granularity = 1.0
        rightAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false
    }

    func resetChart() {
        clearAllViewportJobs()
        removeAnimation()
        clearValues()
        clear()
        data = nil
        rightAxis.customYMax = 0
        rightAxis.customYMin = 0
        zoom(scaleX: 0, scaleY: 0, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
    
}
```

As this is random, I am unable to find why the entries object's address is corrupted in ChartDataSet.swift

Comment: Can you post either more of your code, the actual error log or ideally both to understand what's going on. For example, I'm interested in seeing how you are instantiating the Chartview class as well as the data entries "data".

Comment: @Marmaduk I have updated the relevant code snippets asked by you. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35108870/13894513

Comment: @Marmaduk I have and it isn't relevant as the crash occurs randomly and otherwise the chart is drawn perfectly most of the time.

Comment: Ok, couple questions. At what point does the crash occur? Before super view loaded, during, after, or upon interaction with the chart view? I may not be able to answer the question but I'll try to help pinpoint the error with you.

Comment: My hint for you would be to look into breakpoints with Xcode. Do some debugging, at which line precisely this error is thrown. This might narrow down where the problem is

Comment: @Marmaduk Superview loads fine. I have multiple IBActions which are used to call drawChart() when I want to redraw the chart, so the crash occurs when interacting with the chart view. The crash occurs when the chart is being drawn. The same can be validated from the crash stack.

Comment: @Michael I have tried that. However, as per the stack, the crash is happening randomly and  when BarLineChartViewBase.draw() is called. As far as I understand, draw() method of a view is called asynchronously by the system as per the runloop. Also, the drawing part is within the library, so I am unable to debug it.